# Using Apache Camel Web Service to post and get batches of customers

Tags: split, queue, aggregate, routes

**Use Case**

1. System A posts a list of 500 customers to a web method in a Camel route.
2. The route operation splits the list into individual customers.
3. The customers are aggregated into 5 batches of 100 customers.

Note: I've implemented the web methods in Camel using the CXFRS component.

1. An hour later, System B...
2. Calls a web method to get first batch of 100 customers.
3. Posts a web method to acknowledge the first batch has been processed.
4. Repeats the cycle for the other 4 batches.

**What is the best way to implement this use case in Camel?**

I have a partial implementation using Camel's XML DSL. Currently, my Camel route provides CXFRS methods to split and aggregate the incoming messages into the size required for System B. What is the best way to use Camel components to store the batches until System B requests each batch? Should I use ActiveMQ or some other data store like a database or file system?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ would be the good option